# How to use cursors to iterate through the result set of GET followers/list in Twitter API using c#?

Tags: c#, api, visual-studio-2012, twitter

I have been trying a way to get the data in the next page of the result set of GET followers/list API call. I can get the default data set with the data of first 20 followers and not the others. To get the data of other followers i have to access the next page using the next_cursor but it's not working. I tried using the pseudo-code mentioned in this link. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/misc/cursoring

Is it a must to use this(this is mentioned in the dev. site):

```
var api-path = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/endpoint.json?screen_name=targetUser"
```

Because I have been using the resource URL as,

```
var resource_url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/list.json";
```

and I tried appending the next_cursor to the same resource URL.

```
var url_with_cursor = resource_url + "&cursor=" + 1463101490306580067;
```

and then created the request.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url_with_cursor);
```

but I'm getting an exception in this line when getting the response.

```
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

The error I'm getting is

```
The Remote Server returned an Error 401 Unauthorized
```

Can someone tell the exact way to do cursor-ing, or the exact way to include the cursor in the request. I'm using a asp.net C# web application.

Here's my code, The **oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, oauth_consumer_key, oauth_consumer_secret, oauth_version and oauth_signature_method** are defined in my application

```
    var resource_url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/list.json";
    var cursor = "-1";

    do
    {
        var url_with_cursor = resource_url + "&cursor=" + cursor;


        // unique request details
        var oauth_nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(
            new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));
        var timeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow
            - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        var oauth_timestamp = Convert.ToInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString();

        // create oauth signature
        var baseFormat = "oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_nonce={1}&oauth_signature_method={2}" +
                        "&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_token={4}&oauth_version={5}";

        var baseString = string.Format(baseFormat,
                                    oauth_consumer_key,
                                    oauth_nonce,
                                    oauth_signature_method,
                                    oauth_timestamp,
                                    oauth_token,
                                    oauth_version
            //,Uri.EscapeDataString(status)
                                    );

        baseString = string.Concat("GET&", Uri.EscapeDataString(resource_url), "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(baseString));

        var compositeKey = string.Concat(Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_secret),
                                "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token_secret));

        string oauth_signature;
        using (HMACSHA1 hasher = new HMACSHA1(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(compositeKey)))
        {
            oauth_signature = Convert.ToBase64String(
                hasher.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(baseString)));
        }

        // create the request header
        var headerFormat = "OAuth oauth_nonce=\"{0}\", oauth_signature_method=\"{1}\", " +
                           "oauth_timestamp=\"{2}\", oauth_consumer_key=\"{3}\", " +
                           "oauth_token=\"{4}\", oauth_signature=\"{5}\", " +
                           "oauth_version=\"{6}\"";

        var authHeader = string.Format(headerFormat,
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_nonce),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature_method),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_key),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_version)
                        );


        // make the request
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;     

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url_with_cursor);
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();



        string result = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        JObject j = JObject.Parse(result);
        JArray data = (JArray)j["users"];
        cursor = (String)j["next_cursor_str"];

} while (!cursor.Equals("0"));
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Microsoft Visual Studio?

Comment: Shouldn't it be "?cursor=" since it appears to be the first parameter?

Comment: @cullub : yes i'm using visual studio 2012

Comment: @Dirk : i tried it that way as well, but it's not working.

Comment: @Isu are you using .net?  WPF? Winforms?

Comment: *"but i'm getting an exception in this line when getting the response."* And what exactly is the exception?

Comment: @cullub: i'm using .NET

Comment: @Isu Are you using WPF (User Control, with Xaml), or Winforms (Windows Forms Application)?

Comment: @Dirk: this is the exception i'm getting "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

Comment: @Isu Actually, if you are using a WPFWebApplication, that would be WPF.

Comment: This exception should clearly be part of your question as it's quite important. Looks like you can't simply access that page without some sort of authentication.

Comment: @Isu If you are getting a 401 Error Unauthorized, you probably need to authenticate to the website you are connecting to.  Also, if you use a proxy, you might need to authenticate to that.

Comment: @cullub: i'm using ASP.NET Web Forms Application.

Comment: @Dirk: I did the authentication part in my code. I can get the data of 1st 20 followers without putting a cursor. But i can't get the data of next 20 followers which is in the next page of the result set

Comment: the cursor is the problem :/ and may be the way i'm putting it to the request is wrong. but i can't figure out where i have done wrong.

Comment: Are you sure the API path is formatted correctly?

Comment: @cullub: i didn't put that in my code because it includes something called **endpoint**.

And, the twitter dev site says, "_To retrieve cursored results, you initially pass a cursor with a value of -1 to the_ **endpoint**"

I can't figure out a way to send the cursor to the endpoint :/

Answer (score 1):

you should make a different call to authenticate, by an authorization request. Once that has been granted, you can call the webresponse with the cursor. See my sample code below (Take special note to the StartCreateCall method, where the authentication is done. The data from Twitter is then retrieved by the CallData method):

```
public partial class twitter_followers : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string strTwiterFollowers { get; set; }
    private List<TwiterFollowers> listFollowers = new List<TwiterFollowers>();
    private string screen_name = string.Empty;

    // oauth application keys
    private string oauth_consumer_key = string.Empty;
    private string oauth_consumer_secret = string.Empty;

    // oauth implementation details
    private string resource_urlFormat = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/list.json?screen_name={0}&cursor={1}";

    // unique request details
    private string oauth_nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //just get your request parameters from the config file.
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[GetVariableName(() => screen_name)])) {
            screen_name = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[GetVariableName(() => screen_name)];
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[GetVariableName(() => oauth_consumer_key)]))
        {
            oauth_consumer_key = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[GetVariableName(() => oauth_consumer_key)];
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[GetVariableName(() => oauth_consumer_secret)]))
        {
            oauth_consumer_secret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[GetVariableName(() => oauth_consumer_secret)];
        }
        StartCreateCall();
    }

    // Do the authenticate by an authorization request
    private void StartCreateCall() {
        // You need to set your own keys and screen name
        var oAuthUrl = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token";

        // Do the Authenticate
        var authHeaderFormat = "Basic {0}";

        var authHeader = string.Format(authHeaderFormat,
            Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_key) + ":" +
            Uri.EscapeDataString((oauth_consumer_secret)))
        ));

        var postBody = "grant_type=client_credentials";

        HttpWebRequest authRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(oAuthUrl);
        authRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
        authRequest.Method = "POST";
        authRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
        authRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

        using (Stream stream = authRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            byte[] content = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postBody);
            stream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
        }

        authRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");

        WebResponse authResponse = authRequest.GetResponse();
        // deserialize into an object
        TwitAuthenticateResponse twitAuthResponse;
        using (authResponse)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(authResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var objectText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                twitAuthResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TwitAuthenticateResponse>(objectText);
            }
        }
        //now we have been granted access and got a token type with authorization token from Twitter
        //in the form of a TwitAuthenticateResponse object, we can retrieve the data recursively with a cursor
        CallData(twitAuthResponse, authHeader, cursor);

        int totalFollowers = listFollowers.Count;
        lblTotalFollowers.Text = screen_name + " has " + listFollowers.Count + " Followers";

        Random objRnd = new Random();
        List<TwiterFollowers> randomFollowers = listFollowers.OrderBy(item => objRnd.Next()).ToList<TwiterFollowers>();
        foreach (TwiterFollowers tw in randomFollowers)
        {
            strTwiterFollowers = strTwiterFollowers + "<li><a target='_blank' title='" + tw.ScreenName + "' href=https://twitter.com/" + tw.ScreenName + "><img src='" + tw.ProfileImage + "'/><span>" + tw.ScreenName + "</span></a></li>";
        }
    }

    //Retrieve the data from Twitter recursively with a cursor
    private void CallData(TwitAuthenticateResponse twitAuthResponse, string authHeader, string cursor)
    {
        try {
            JObject j = GetJSonObject(twitAuthResponse, authHeader, cursor);
            JArray data = (JArray)j["users"];
            if (data != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in data)
                {
                    TwiterFollowers objTwiterFollowers = new TwiterFollowers();
                    objTwiterFollowers.ScreenName = item["screen_name"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                    objTwiterFollowers.ProfileImage = item["profile_image_url"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                    objTwiterFollowers.UserId = item["id"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                    listFollowers.Add(objTwiterFollowers);
                }

                JValue next_cursor = (JValue)j["next_cursor"];
                if (long.Parse(next_cursor.Value.ToString()) > 0)
                {
                    //Get the following data from Twitter with the next cursor
                    CallData(twitAuthResponse, authHeader, next_cursor.Value.ToString());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //do nothing
        }
    }

    private JObject GetJSonObject(TwitAuthenticateResponse twitAuthResponse, string authHeader, string cursor)
    {
        string resource_url = string.Format(resource_urlFormat, screen_name, cursor);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cursor))
        {
            resource_url = resource_url.Substring(0, resource_url.IndexOf("&cursor"));
        }

        HttpWebRequest fRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(resource_url);
        var timelineHeaderFormat = "{0} {1}";
        fRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", string.Format(timelineHeaderFormat, twitAuthResponse.token_type, twitAuthResponse.access_token));
        fRequest.Method = "Get";
        WebResponse response = fRequest.GetResponse();
        string result = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        return JObject.Parse(result);
    }

    private string GetVariableName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expr)
    {
        var body = (MemberExpression)expr.Body;
        return body.Member.Name;
    }

    private class TwitAuthenticateResponse
    {
        public string token_type { get; set; }
        public string access_token { get; set; }
    }

    private class TwiterFollowers
    {
        public string ScreenName { get; set; }
        public string ProfileImage { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tweetinvi would make it somewhat easier for you.

Please visit https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/Get-All-Followers-Code to have an idea on how to do it including `RateLimit` handling.

Without considering the RateLimits, you could simply use the following code.

```
long nextCursor = -1;

do
{
    var query = string.Format("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json?screen_name={0}", username);

    var results = TwitterAccessor.ExecuteCursorGETCursorQueryResult<IIdsCursorQueryResultDTO>(query, cursor: cursor).ToArray();

    if (results.Any())
    {
        nextCursor = results.Last().NextCursor;
    }
    else
    {
        nextCursor = -1;
    }
}
while (nextCursor != -1 && nextCursor != 0);
```

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Here you go, I have now added a simple example :)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting "401 Unauthorized"
Did you check you are setting everything right?
Credentials? Check both queries on fiddler.

Comment: Yes. I did the authorization part. What do u mean by queries bdw?

Comment: after appending the cursor to the request only i'm getting the error. :/

Comment: I recommend you to familiarize with fiddler
[fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) is easy, just create a console app, make the request and you will see what is happening when you make the requests

Comment: Or you can provide more code to see if there is more error in the whole context of the logic

Comment: I provided the code which i'm using. And i will try using fiddler as well.

Comment: why are you signing the request with the resource_url instead of url_with_cursor?

Comment: Oops! My bad.. U meant signing the request noh, will try it.. I didnt notice that the whole time.. :O