# Twitter API returns 401 - unauthorized

Tags: c#, .net, twitter, oauth

I am having problems with twitter API. All I want to achieve is that users will be able to login through twitter on my web site.

I am using this library:
[Twitter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1006013/OAuth-Social-logins-open-source-library-Facebook-G)

Library works well for google and facebook, but with twitter I can't make it work.

I am receiving:

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401)
>   Unauthorized.

What I've already tried:

Set access token on twitter developers console and pasted this access token to header.

I've followed instructions from [this link on twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/authorizing-requests)
and created 'Authorization' header. It doesn't work, exception is still 401 - not authorized.

The one thing that I don't understand is in [this link](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes).

The explanation for 401 error is:

> Authentication credentials were missing or incorrect. Also returned
>   in other circumstances, for example all calls to API v1 endpoints now
>   return 401 (use API v1.1 instead).

So, all calls for API v1 will return 401. 'Use API v1.1 instead' - how to do this? Where is the setting to use v1.1 instead of v1 ?

Here is method from original code, with my modifications - adding 'Authorization' header:

```
namespace Oauth2Login.Core
{
    public class RestfullRequest
    {
        public static string Request(string url, string method, string contentType, NameValueCollection authorizationHeader,
            string data, string proxyAddress = null)
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = method;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType))
                request.ContentType = contentType;

            string authHeaderString = "OAuth ";
            authHeaderString += PercentEncode("oauth_consumer_key") + "=\"" + (authorizationHeader.GetValues("oauth_consumer_key"))[0] + "\", ";
            authHeaderString += PercentEncode("oauth_nonce") + "=\"" + PercentEncode((authorizationHeader.GetValues("oauth_nonce"))[0]) + "\", ";
            authHeaderString += PercentEncode("oauth_signature") + "=\"" + PercentEncode((authorizationHeader.GetValues("oauth_signature"))[0]) + "\", ";
            authHeaderString += PercentEncode("oauth_signature_method") + "=\"" + PercentEncode((authorizationHeader.GetValues("oauth_signature_method"))[0]) + "\", ";
            authHeaderString += PercentEncode("oauth_timestamp") + "=\"" + PercentEncode((authorizationHeader.GetValues("oauth_timestamp"))[0]) + "\", ";
            authHeaderString += PercentEncode("oauth_token") + "=\"" + PercentEncode((authorizationHeader.GetValues("oauth_token"))[0]) + "\", ";
            authHeaderString += PercentEncode("oauth_version") + "=\"" + PercentEncode((authorizationHeader.GetValues("oauth_version"))[0]) + "\"";

            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeaderString);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(proxyAddress))
            {
                IWebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(proxyAddress);
                proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential();
                request.Proxy = proxy;
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
            {
                using (var swt = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    swt.Write(data);
                }
            }

            string result = string.Empty;

            /*this line throws 401 - not authorized exception*/
            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    result = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        public static string PercentEncode(string source)
        {
            return source
                .Replace(" ", "%20").Replace("!", "%21").Replace("&", "%26")
                .Replace(@"/", "%2F").Replace("=", "%3D").Replace("+", "%2B")
                .Replace(",", "%2C").Replace("-", "%2D").Replace(".", "%2E");
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might help you:

[How to use cursors to iterate through the result set of GET followers/list in Twitter API using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25605640/how-to-use-cursors-to-iterate-through-the-result-set-of-get-followers-list-in-tw/37079147#37079147)

Check the part until the comment '//now we have been granted access...' in the private void StartCreateCall() method.